# 4 errores al compilar

Tags: java, compilar

Este es el Código de la clase `Linea`. Tenía el `public class Linea` y se lo quite y lo deje en `class Linea` siguiendo un consejo de una respuesta anterior pero a la hora de compilar me da 4 errores pero todos ellos provienen de un mismo error, crep yo... igual adjunto imagen de los errores.

```
class Linea {        
  private Punto p0; 
  private double m; 
  public Linea(Punto p, double s) {
    p0 = p;
    m = s;
  }

  public double getPendiente() {
    return m;
  }

  public double interseccionY() {
    return (p0.y()-m*p0.x());
  }
  
  public boolean equals(Linea l) {
    return (getPendiente() == l.getPendiente() &&
      interseccionY() == l.interseccionY());
  }
  
  public String toString() {
    return new String("y = " + (float)m + "x + " + (float)interseccionY());
  }
}

public class PruebaLinea {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Punto p = new Punto(5,-4);
    Linea l1 = new Linea(p,-2);
    System.out.println("La linea 1 es " + l1);
    System.out.println("Su pendiente es " + l1.getPendiente() + ", su interseccion con y es " + l1.interseccionY());
    Linea l2 = new Linea(p,-1);
    System.out.println("La linea 2 es " + l2);
    System.out.println("Su pendiente es " + l2.getPendiente() + ", su interseccion con y es " + l2.interseccionY());
    
    if (l1.equals(l2))
      System.out.println("Las lineas son iguales");
    else
      System.out.println("Las lineas no son iguales");
  }
}
```

**Este es el código y aquí abajo están los errores**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: listo, ya lo edito...

Comment: Te falta crear la clase Punto.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no es capaz de reconocer la clase Punto porque no la has creado.
Si la tienes creada y en el mismo proyecto pon arriba del todo: `import package.Punto;`.
En package pon la dirección del directorio donde se encuentra.